# How to change Desktop, Download, Music and ... path?

Tags: .desktop, environment

How can I rename Desktop, Download, Music, Pictures & ... folders names to desktop, download, music, pictures & ... .

NOTE: I'd simply rename them by mv command, but still have troubles. Because when clicking on places panel, get the following error:

```
Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.
Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/home/mehrshad/Documents': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does `ls` show the directories?

Comment: it's better to leave the default/core folders as they are to avoid any issues.

Comment: Do the following to get rid of the error:

Open terminal and type:

>`nano ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Change the line:

>`XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"`

to:

>`>`XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/pictures"`

Log-out and log-in.

Answer (score 0):

Simply right click and rename....

Beware though, although this technically should be possible without problems, some projects may rely on the files in those folders so you may run into path errors.